# How to iterate though all tags inside one?

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing, gpx

I want to read `gpx` file to get all `wpt`'s inside `gpx` tag. I'm using this Google's guide for it:
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml#read

It's working but i'm getting only first `wpt` instead all of them :(

I tried to use

`while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) { // iterate }`

instead

`while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) { }`

and it's working but i think it's not optimal. So how can i make iteration through whole `gpx` tag?

My xml file structue is:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<gpx version="1.1">
    <wpt lat="53.20507" lon="45.15311">
        <name>My Point</name>
        <sym>magenta</sym></wpt>
    <wpt lat="53.21941" lon="44.99925">
        <name>Point</name>
        <sym>default</sym>
    </wpt>
</gpx>
```

Comment: change parser.Next() with parser.hasNext() or use this library [link](https://jsoup.org/)

Comment: @OneDev there is no `hasNext()` method :(

Comment: use this `int eventType = parser.getEventType(); while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) `